# Android, IOS force pressing on the screen

Tags: android, ios, screen

Is there any way to measure the force (weight) clicking on the screen in Android or IOS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Android there is [MotionEvent.getPressure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure%28int%29).

As far as I know iOS does not have a way to get pressure information.

Comment: Thank u for answer. I thought I might be in IOS can measure the speed of reaction to touch. The heavier the object to the rate of reaction will be faster, thereby pre-made calculation of weight on the reaction rate. But I think this is not the most accurate version, from the category of fiction :)

Answer (score 0):

Speaking for iOS: there is no possibility to obtain the force employed when touching the screen.