# How to measure the force of pressure on the Web?

Tags: javascript, web, touch, tablet

Recently Apple introduced a new trackpad, which supports the "Force Touch" feature. It is similar to Wacom tablets for painting because, with special software, you can measure the force (weight) of pressing.
So, is it possible to get these values using web-technologies like javascript? Do browsers provide any API and information about pressing force?
P.S. I find this question relative to mine one, but it is not about the web: [Android, IOS force pressing on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000217/android-ios-force-pressing-on-the-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `pressure` attribute of a [**PointerEvent**](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#pointerevent-interface). [This isn't widely supported across browsers yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer), as it's not a final spec, but as of this writing [IE11 has some support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772360(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The best answer ever! Thank you very much :) It works, tested.

Answer (score 1):

For both iOS (iPhone 6s) and Mac (new MabBook Pro with Force Touch) you can use [Pressure.js](http://pressurejs.com/). It is a JavaScript library that allows you to simply use force touch on the web. Here is an example of the basic usage:

```
Pressure.set('#element', {
  change: function(force, event){
    // this is called every time there is a change in pressure
  },
  unsupported: function(){
    // this is called if device or browser does not support Force or 3D touch
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like now we have MouseEvent.webkitForce and so on.

Comment: @MaximMazurok exactly. But it gets complicated using that because you have to loop repeatedly over the event to get get the updated force, as well as other issues like detecting if it is supported. Pressure.js takes care of all of that and has support for Mac Force Touch also by default. So it works on iPhone 6s and new Macs and the new Mac Trackpad